# interception coordinates of polygons Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, folium

I have two set of polygons gps coordinates (like on the picture). Is it possible in matplotlib (or maybe another library) to get coordinates of polygon which is intersection of two given polygons? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Although it may be overkill, but I recommend to use the [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) package. An example is shown [here](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html#calculate-intersection-between-two-geometries) which does exactly what you ask.

Matplotlib is only a plotting library so I don't think you can use it to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: mpl does have some internal path computation tools (which we use for computing clipping) but using `shapely` is probably a better idea.

Comment: Example which you provede from osgeo library? Shouldn't it be from shapely lib?

Comment: As you can see from the Shapely website "Shapely is a Python package for set-theoretic analysis and manipulation of planar features using functions from the well known and widely deployed GEOS library."

Comment: For your task, actually osgeo is enough, sharply is higher level library and thus easier to use, one sharply example [here](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#collections)